# dark mode local storage not working react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, local-storage, redux-actions

Hey everybody hope you are fine
I am trying to set the dark mode for my react app and I am then updating the state containing dark mode but the problem is that even after using `localStorage` I am unable to make it on reload

```
  const { modes } = useSelector((state) => state.DarkMode);
  console.log("this is modes " + modes);

const onChangeButton = () =>{
  let modeSet = localStorage.getItem("moding")
  if (modeSet === null) {
    modeSet = true
    localStorage.setItem("moding",modeSet)
  }
  else if (modeSet !== null){
    if (modeSet === true) { 
      modeSet = false;
      localStorage.setItem("moding",modeSet)
      console.log("iam in true");
    } else {
      modeSet = true;
      localStorage.setItem("moding",modeSet)
      console.log("iam in false");
    }
  }
  dispatch(setDarkMode(modeSet));
}

  useEffect(() => {
    onChangeButton();
  }, []);
```

and I am also changing it with a button

```
   <button className="modeBtn modeBtn1" onClick={() =>onChangeButton()} style={{color: `${modes ? "white" : "black"}`, backgroundColor: `${modes ? "black" : "white"}`,}}>{`${modes ? "Light ☀️" : "Dark "}`}</button>
```

and in the redux actions which is the main function of changing the state is

```
export const setDarkMode = (moder) => async (dispatch) => {

  console.log("this is inside moder " + moder);
  let data = moder;
  dispatch({
    type: SET_DARK_MODE,
    payload: data,
  });
};
```

the problem is that when I change the theme with the button it takes changing the mode to the dark mode and works fine but when I reload it moves back again to the white mode.
how can I make it stay and change on button.

Comment: In the else block either use `==` or use `Boolean(modeSet)`, cause local storage returns a string and you are strictly comparing with a boolean value it will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

include your mode selecting code inside the `useEffect` block you will need `localStorage.getItem` to be called on first render to detect the stored value

Comment: I change it and made a function so it could work with button as well but it is still not working